# Can an outdoor weatherproof electrical box use an inside outlet?

Tags: electrical, outdoor

Let’s say I have an outdoor weatherproof electrical box on the front of my house. Can I use a regular ‘ol outlet instead it, or are there special ones intended for external use?

Comment: You'll either need a GFCI outlet or a GFCI breaker on the circuit.

Comment: If youre asking "plain outlet" I have not heard of an outdoor type.  If you are talking "GFCI outlet" then they won't protect that. However a smarter installer will use skill to put the GFCI protective device inside, and that means you get to use a plain outlet and indoor GFCI device.